# Swiper.js : doesn't work Fade effect in Svelte kit

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit, swiper.js

My swiper version is ^10.0.4.
I tried to apply all the results of the search, but the fade effect still doesn't work.

JavaScript

```js
import Swiper from "swiper/bundle";
import "swiper/css/bundle";
import "swiper/css/effect-fade";
import { onMount } from "svelte";

onMount(() => {
  var listArray = ["slide1", "slide2", "slide3", "slide4"];
  var mainSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    effect: "fade",
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: "true",
      type: "bullets",
      renderBullet: function (index, className) {
        return (
          '<span class="' +
          className +
          '">' +
          "<i></i>" +
          "<b></b>" +
          "</span>"
        );
      },
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    autoplay: {
      delay: 3000,
    },
    speed: 1,
  });
  var pagingSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination-square",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
  mainSwiper.controller.control = pagingSwiper;
}); //onMount
```

HTML

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pag_wrap">
    <div class="swiper-button-next" />
    <div class="swiper-button-prev" />
    <div class="swiper-pagination" />
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination-square" />
</div>
```

If I add  [effect: "fade"] this one at

```js
[var mainSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper",{})]
```

I can't see it on the screen except for the first slide.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for days I finally figured out why.

Add this one at style:

```
swiper-wrapper {transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0)!important; }
```

Hope this helps someone who has the same issue as me.